# Wordpress query showing only some data

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to display the latest post with specific html/css properties. My current solution however is showing only the title and url to the post (no date or excerpt).

Here is my "function version #1" code in functions.php that I call to action in index.php:

```
function latest_article() {
  $content_latest_php = "";

  $query_latest_article = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 1
  ));

  foreach ( $query_latest_article as $post) {
    $content_latest_php = get_template_part( 'content-latest', get_post_format() );
  };

  return $content_latest_php;
};
```

Here is my "function version #2", trying to use different way to achieve the same goal:

```
function latest_article() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
  );

  $query_latest_post = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $query_latest_post->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query_latest_post->have_posts() ) {
        $query_latest_post->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content-latest', get_post_format() );
    }
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
};
```

This is content-latest.php:

```
<div class="article-latest">
  <a class="article-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <img class="article-latest-image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/article-thumbnail.png"></img>
    <div class="article-latest-date"><?php get_the_date(); ?></div>
    <div class="article-latest-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <div class="article-latest-text" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php get_the_excerpt() ?></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

And this is the result I receive while viewing the website with code inspector:

```
<div class="article-latest">
  <a class="article-link" href="http://mywebsite.com/the-latest-post/">
    <img class="article-latest-image" src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/nameofthetheme/img/article-thumbnail.png"></img>
    <div class="article-latest-date"></div>
    <div class="article-latest-title">The name of the latest post</div>
    <div class="article-latest-text" href="http://mywebsite.com/the-latest-post/"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

^ There is no date and no excerpt being loaded. Why is that?

Comment: I managed to show the date of the post by modifying "<?php get_the_date(); ?>" for "<?php **echo** get_the_date(); ?>", however this does still not work for the excerpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `get_the_excerpt()` and `get_the_date()`: both these functions *return* the relevant info, but they *don't output it.* So you either need to `echo`:

```
<?php
echo get_the_date();
echo get_the_excerpt();
?>
```

Or use these function that actually output:

```
<?php
the_date();
the_excerpt();
?>
```

WordPress uses this convention a lot; if a function starts with `get` – `get_the_title()`, `get_the_date()` etc. –  it will usually *return* something rather than output it. Functions starting with `the` usually *output* something to do with the current post in the loop.

To take an example: if you were to look at the source for `the_exerpt()` you'd see that it actually calls `get_the_excerpt()`:

```
function the_excerpt() {

/**
 * Filters the displayed post excerpt.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @see get_the_excerpt()
 *
 * @param string $post_excerpt The post excerpt.
 */
echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I can get the date without a problem! The excerpt is still not loading, but I guess that's not an error of my own code now (right?).

Comment: First, check if the posts actually have excerpts: add `print_r($post);` to the end of  `content-latest.php`. That will print out the post array; if you copy that to comment I'll take a look.

Comment: There is no excerpt I guess: `...[post_excerpt] => [post_status] => ...`, however I thought that it should use the auto-generated one. 

Also, I am using custom excerpt length and more attributes, shouldn't be the cause of my problem tho (?).

Comment: @lelekcze It *should* return an auto-generated excerpt: what filters are you hooking to `get_the_excerpt`? Are you removing any filters?

Comment: I am using `function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;}` and  `function wpdocs_excerpt_more( $more ) {
     return '...';}`, not removing any.

Comment: @lelekcze Hmm. To point you in the right direction: internally, `the_excerpt()` calls `get_the_exerpt()` and applies filters to it. One of the default filters that is applied to it is `wp_trim_excerpt()` (found in `wp-includes/formatting.php`): if the excerpt is empty, *this* is the function that returns a trimmed down version of the content to use as an excerpt. It applies the `wp_trim_excerpt` filters before returning it, so you should check if you've anything hooked to that as well.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your content-latest theme file

```
    <div class="article-latest">
  <a class="article-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <img class="article-latest-image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/article-thumbnail.png"></img></a>
    <?php the_date()('Y-m-d', '<div class="article-latest-date">', '</div>'); ?>
    <div class="article-latest-title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <div class="article-latest-text"><?php the_excerpt() ?></div>
</div>
```